# Are google docs/drive resource_id's globally unique?

Tags: google-drive-api

As a file gets renamed/revised/passed around, can we depend on the resource_id's being globally unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Google Drive File's ID will remain the same regardless of the changes made to the File's metadata and/or content.