# Getting a cross platform UUID

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid

I'm building an app that requires getting a UUID and sending it to my server to get a unique app key (for handling communication with andriod devices reasons).

I am currently using:

```
NSString *id = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

My question is, how can i make sure that any other device using my app won't get the same UUID (i know the odds of that happening are small).

I don't care about persisting the UUID, because i will be using the app key given to me by the server. All i need is to make sure i will get a truly cross platform UUID.

Thanks

Comment: append platform to the id

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: "i know the odds of that happening are small" You don't understand how small. It's been a few months since I did the calculations, but the probability of a collision is like winning the lottery jackpot 3 or 4 drawings in a row.

Comment: Ah, there it is, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687097/900873

Comment: lol..yeah i know, just wanted to know if there is a way to get assurances on that :). Any way i'll continue with that thanks

Comment: if the unique id is string, not GUID and GUID is unique per platform, then cross-platform unique id is simply `GUID+platform`. e.g. 'ios-XXXXXXXXX' for ios device, `mac-XXXXXXXXXXX` for mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to ensure that on the device, you will have to check for uniqueness server side.

Comment: k..i will do that too

Comment: This class offers a claimed-to-be unique identifier.  Doc says for ad serving only.  I've never tried to get an app approved using this, but have a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html